# visibility of button in active view

Tags: yii2

his is my view.php code

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\CasualLeaves */
$this->title = $model->id;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Casual Leaves', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="casual-leaves-view">

<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

<p>
    <?= Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
        'data' => [
            'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
            'method' => 'post',
        ],
    ]) ?>
    <?= Html::a(' Recommended', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::a('Not Recommended', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</p>


<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
    //    'id',
        'name_of_applicant',
        'designation',
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
        'total_number_of_days',
        'reason_for_leave',
        'no_of_leave_already_taken',
        'date_of_request',
      //  'recommendation',
      //  'status',
    ],
]) ?>
```

i have a leave application form.

An applicant create a leave and save.

After clicking create button the applicant only see the update button, that time i want to hide the delete button.

But admin views the delete button when he login and check the application

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please provide more details.

Comment: I also have no clue what you are trying to do!? Please describe the problem again: current situation and problem as well as intended behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sow the delete button only if the user is admin (in the sample test RBAC  can('admin') permission)

```
<p>
<?php 

   echo Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
   if ( Yii::$app->User->can('admin') ){
     echo Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
         'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
         'data' => [
             'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
             'method' => 'post',
         ],
    ]);
 }
echo Html::a('Recommended', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], 
         ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
echo Html::a('Not Recommended', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], 
         ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
?>
</p>
```

Comment: this code is not working , button removed but the code is shown in the form.

Comment: $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest){ Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [ 'class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'data' => [ 'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?', 'method' => 'post', ], ]) } ?>
Name Of Applicant jhghj
Designation b
Start Date 2018-03-01
End Date 2018-03-01
Total Number Of Days 0
Reason For Leave cgdfg
No Of Leave Already Taken 1
Date Of Request 2018-03-01

Comment: thank you..............  my code has inside <?php ..?  ,but i forgot the ; after the html statement